# Is it better to rasterize text into a header image or overlay it as text?

Tags: website-design, accessibility, image

If you want to have a fixed header on a web page that also includes text, is it better to make that text part of the image, or to overlay the text in the header frame (such that the text is selectable, scalable, screen-reader accessible, etc)?

I'm currently in a debate over whether it would be better to embed the text in the header image on our forums. One problem is that if the background image is something we want to repeat horizontally as the page is widened, the text can't be rasterized to it because it would repeat as well - we'd need a transparent image of just the text to overlay on top of the background header image. Also, the background image selected might just fade into a solid colour for stretching, we haven't picked one out yet.

What's to be gained and lost in each scenario?

From looking at other sites on the internet, it seems like the most popular option is to rasterize the text into the header image - but a lot of times this is because the text is highly stylized as part of the logo. In our case, it's just a simple title and caption, like in a blog.

Wikipedia rasterizes:

[image]

Windows Live doesn't:

[image]

Google does for their main logo, but not for their caption:

[image]

Comment: Your examples are logotypes--which typically will have some form of custom typography--which typically means you can't just set them in any-old text.

Comment: "Google does for their main logo, but not for their caption" -- because the logo is in custom 'font' while the caption is not. Logos & Trademarks are not considered 'text' even if all they contain is 'text' in the general sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally do text whenever I can to save bandwidth and optimize a website. what you cannot do in text, that's when you do it in images.

Here are some guidelines I follow:

**Text**

Pros:

- [screen readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741700/how-to-write-good-alt-text-for-images-to-help-screen-reader-and-blind-user-to-un)!
- words/text aka "keywords" add to SEO
- part of the page HTTP request, not another HTTP request
- text can be [compressed on transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).
- are selectable

Cons:

- without CSS3 or at least modern approaches, it's awful!
- fonts (unless you use web-fonts)
- must be styled properly so they won't break

**Images**

Pros:

- if it includes graphics
- if text can't do it alone
- if it includes your logo *that can't be done by text alone*
- cacheable and save-able (obviously)

Cons:

- recently, I browsed a person's portfolio which relied heavily on images (even the text was made into images), they were shrunk on mobile. the large ones cannot be seen instantly. try this site on a mobile, like opera mini: http://www.onin256a.com/projects/
- an added bulk to your HTTP request. see  [why they use sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) instead of individual images[even google sprites images in gmail](https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/sprite_black2.png) to avoid further http requests
- must be [marked-up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741700/how-to-write-good-alt-text-for-images-to-help-screen-reader-and-blind-user-to-un) to be picked up by screen readers
- not easily editable if you don't have the original copy.

Some books I read:

[Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/explore)

[designing with progressive enhancement](http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/)

[Universal Design for Web Applications](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596518745.do)

Comment: Nice list; can you reference the data that caused you to form your opinion for each point?

Comment: actually, it's a set of guidelines i have followed eversince i started developing for the web. others are obvious reasons also. some come from web optimization. but i have read these books: http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/, http://designingwebinterfaces.com/explore, and http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596518745.do

Comment: Why don't you add those into your answer (and explain what parts of each book is relevant for the OP)?

Answer (score 6):

Probably the only reason to rasterize the text is special visual effects that would be difficult to achieve by other means. Every other factor that I can think of would be in favor of live text. You mentioned some of the reasons yourself. Another very important reason is SEO - the crawlers can't see rasterized text, so if it's important to you that your site name lead to your website, you should use live text.

Comment: With all the features/power of CSS3, there's actually very little reason to rasterize text anymore. See: CSS Shadow, CSS @font-face, CSS 3D, etc. Here's a [link](http://hallofhavoc.com/2011/03/cool-text-effects-using-css3-text-shadow/) with a handful of cool effects.

Answer (score 4):

### Rasterized text in a logo:

The good:

1. Makes your logo portable: it can be copied and pasted with no need for CSS
2. Works in all browsers: CSS text effects and @fontface fonts may display differently on different browsers, images ensure the logo will always look the same
3. Allows a great deal more customization than text: you can make each letter an image or generally do anything you can in an image.

The bad:

1. Not ready by screen readers: you'll have to use an `alt` attribute for accessability.
2. Bandwidth use and load times: no amount of CSS can waste as much space as an image.
3. Harder to style: You'll have to edit the original image to make an image header fit a new style or website. Text is easy to style in CSS.

### Text

The Good:

1. Easy to style and suit any website: CSS3 makes this even easier and allows for graceful degredation and targeted styles.
2. Easy to target mobile devices: Mobile is just a media query away.
3. Accessible: It's text, screen readers will read it just as you lay it out.

The bad:

1. CSS and photoshop are different skills.
2. More limited.
3. Only modern browsers will see the very shinyiest of CSS3 and HTML5 effects.

The main benefit of an image is that it's easier to make one time and you can do some more advanced stuff with it. Long term however text generally wins out, especially in the age of CSS3, where **we can make beautiful *type* rather than beautiful *pictures of type***. With the web's dynamic nature, pretty pictures of text don't cut it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As things stand today, I would suggest using 'text' in images only when it is a work of art, thus excluding the question of font rasterization.

In all other cases, it is possible and it is recommended to use text in all its purity.

Answer (score 2):

Desktops, laptops, tablets, phones. It is always recommended that you maintain your look on any kind of layout. Text is always **responsive**. Then you apply CSS3 and generate effects. Even those effects are going to be **responsive**.

PS: As you have mentioned 'Text' in your question, I am only talking about 'Text'. Be it the 'Text' of logo or menu bar or any other image.

Comment: Not sure how 'Text' of logo or menu bar or any other image are each different. Can you pl elaborate?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're not sure about. I was talking about keeping layout responsive. As layout consists of many things, I clarified that I'm talking about only 'Text'. Btw, you made a good point in your answer - "I would suggest using 'text' in images only when it is a work of art"